# Media Picker is not working on orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

when in blog post, i tried to upload picture using media picker but it's not uploaded, when i debugged it , the media path is empty, I already set the base url just like the web url but it's still not working,
please help.
Thanks

Comment: In the WYSIWYG editor? Can you upload files from the media manager screen? Are you using Azure, file system for storage? Version of orchard? More info dude

Comment: I can see two buttons for inserting media, the 1st button is "Insert/Update Media" where I can directly upload an image without choosing a folder and use it on my post. The 2nd button is "Insert Media" where I need to select which folder to save the picture and after that I can use it on my blog post. The 2nd button is working but the 1st button when I upload, it didn't work.